# Why does my For loop only print the last result?

Tags: for-loop, pascal

I am trying to program a for loop that will multiply a given number n with every number in a certain range (e.g. 1-10), printing every step. My code for this looks like this:

```
begin
     writeln('FOR');
     for i:=1 to 10 do
     x:=n*i;
     writeln(x);
     readln();
     end;
```

However, only the last result will be printed. In case of n=5, it would be 50.
How do I fix this?

Kind regards,
Julius

Without the x:=n*i; line, it will print 0 ten times, as it should do. Also, replacing x with n in the writeln line will print n 10 times.

Answer (score 5):

You're (1) missing the `begin` and `end` for the `for` loop, and (2) have confused yourself with inconsistent indentation.

With consistent indentation, your code would be:

```
begin
    writeln('FOR');
    for i:=1 to 10 do
        x:=n*i;
    writeln(x);
    readln();
end;
```

As you can see, without a `begin` and `end` for the loop, only the immediate next line of code is the actual loop body.  Include a `begin` and `end` block to specify multiple lines of code in the loop body:

```
begin
    writeln('FOR');
    for i:=1 to 10 do
    begin
        x:=n*i;
        writeln(x);
    end;
    readln();
end;
```